# Which MacBook(Pro) for running Visual Studio 2010 on VMWare Fusion on a Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vmware-fusion

Anyone have experience running Visual Studio 2010 on a MacBook or MacBook Pro?  (via VMWare fusion)

Any feedback / advice based on your experience re what level of MacBook Pro (i.e. CPU type, CPU speed) you would target to get reasonable/good performance from VS2010 on it?

(I'm just concerned about getting a base level MacBook Pro 13" 2.4GHz Core2Duo whether I would be frustrated with performance or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually run 2-3 instances of VS2010 RTM on my 13" macbook (2.0 ghz), running in VMWare fusion with 1 core and 1.5 GB ram, and I've never been especially bothered by the speed in the RTM.  That being said, I don't use designers, intellitrace, TFS, etc., so those may still be problematic.

Answer (score 4):

My MacBook Pro has a 2.4 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo processor and  4GB of RAM. I haven't used VMWare fusion, but using parallels I found that performance is just too frustratingly sluggish to develop with Visual Studio. I ended up creating a Windows partition on my machine which runs like a dream. I still use parallels to connect to the Windows partition from Mac OS X (Snow leopard) if I want to quickly check something in Visual Studio or do something quick in Windows. If I want to do some proper windows development though, I always boot directly into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well my mate is running Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 on VirtualBox OSE running on Debian running on a two year old MacBook. (Or however they called those in these days). Of course it depends on what you wanna do. If you're into 3d directx programming or shiny wpf applications with lots of shadows and blurs - debugging will be a pain in the ass on any virtual windows machine which doesn't support 3d acceleration (hardware that is).